# When a key is pressed, the event occurs twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keyevent

When I press a key using keyEvent, then I call the function, it is below.

```
const GeneratedKey: FC<IGenerated> = (props) => {

    const [keyBoard, setKeyBoard] = useState("")
    const [arrayMovie, setArrayMovie] = useState<string[]>([])
    const idPage = props.idpage
    const nameMovie = data.results[idPage].title
    const [idLetter, setIdLetter] = useState<number>(0)
    const [indexArray, setIndexArray] = useState<number[]>([])
    const arrayNameMovie = nameMovie.split(" ").join("").split("");
    
    const getKey = (e: any) => {
        console.log("test")
        const key = e.key
        let count = 0
        for (let i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
            if (key.toUpperCase() == String.fromCharCode(i)) {
                count = 1
            } else if (key.toLowerCase() == "backspace") {
                count = 10
            }
        }
        if (count == 1) {
            indexArray.sort(function (a: any, b: any) {
                return a - b;
            })
            arrayMovie.splice(indexArray[idLetter], 1, key)
            setIdLetter(idLetter + 1)
        } else if (count == 10) {
            if (idLetter >= 1) {
                setIdLetter(idLetter - 1)
                arrayMovie.splice(indexArray[idLetter], 1, "")
            }
        }
        setKeyBoard(key)
        document.removeEventListener("keydown", getKey);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        for (let i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
            const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayNameMovie.length)
            arrayNameMovie.splice(randomIndex, 1, " ")
            indexArray.push(randomIndex)
        }
        setIdLetter(indexArray[0])
        setArrayMovie(arrayNameMovie)
    }, [])

    document.addEventListener("keydown", getKey)

    return (
        <div className="down__word">
            {arrayMovie.map((letter: any) =>
                <LettersView letters={letter} props={undefined} />
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

In fact, it should be called once, but it fires twice, as you can see from `console.log();`
How can I fix this, I can also show other files with code, but this is unlikely to help

Comment: add a console.log before addEventListener to check if your component created twice

Comment: @emptyhua yes, console.log it works twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to your component may get rendered twice (due to change of props or any external reason). Moreover I think this is not the correct way to handle the event listener in FC. You should consider the `useEffect` for registration / un-registration of event listener.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handler = () => {};
  document.addEventListener('keydown', handler);
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', handler);
  }
}, [deps]); // if you have any changing dependency else just remove the array to execute the UseEffect everytime.
```

This will ensure that you have registered the event only once in your code.

Refer https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Dependency array for your useEffect. Like when to execute the useEffect hook. Follow the official doc. you will get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but now my data in the array does not change, and specifically, I mean the line `arrayMovie.splice (indexArray [idLetter], 1, key)`, could you tell me more about this?

Comment: that is may be due to the 2nd optional argument array. You may choose to have 2 useEffect in your code, one for event listener (with empty, filled or no 2nd array argument at all, based on your requirement) and another one for managing your array with empty array as 2nd arg. Remember you need to understand the role of 2nd array argument first.